# How to type a Simplified Chinese degree symbol on a regular English keyboard?

Tags: simplified-characters

Anyone knows how to type a Simplified Chinese degree symbol (°) on a regular English keyboard? Thanks.

Comment: What is a "Simplified Chinese degree symbol"? Are you talking about「度」?

Comment: @droooze I would've thought s/he meant some full-space Chinese version of the degree symbol like ， instead of , but [there's no such unicode mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol). I would've thought s/he meant some fast encoding of the degree symbol on Chinese keyboards, but default Chinese keyboards don't produce degree signs either. So, yeah, I have no idea what they're talking about.

Comment: I tried to display °(Alt+0176) in my Chinese application. It displayed garbage when I compiled and ran my program. I assume there must be a different ° in Chinese code page. I may have found one a minute ago, which is Atl+0186. It displays a ° with an underscore. Not sure if it is the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Chinese word processors have the option to use `U+2103` ℃ or `U+2104` ℉, to get over the typographical problem of displaying a degree much closer to the C or F than otherwise allowable in fullwidth text.

However, it is also true that the Chinese 度 is used more commonly in everyday text and in most newspapers; my personal contact with ℃ has been in academic papers.

Both of these are in the Unicode block "[Letterlike Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterlike_Symbols)", alongside ℏ, the  "Planck constant Over Two Pi" `U+210F` and Ω the Ohm sign `U+2126`; most common is likely the ™ trademark sign `U+2122`, also repurposed in modern Chinese's Internet slang.

Answer (score 1):

In China，people use input software to type.For me,I choose Baidu Input.So I just type "du" on keyboard,then I can choose ° from it，or as I type "wendu" on keyboard,℃ is on the list for choose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should need a Chinese Input application. You can use this symbol："。。。。。"